# PhpStorm using incorrect namespaces

Tags: namespaces, phpstorm, psr-0

I have an issue with my PhpStorm using incorrect namespaces when creating a new class.

**Example:**
I have a module named `Booking`. Inside `Booking` I want to create a controller called `StatusController`. The directory the controller class will be created in is Booking/src/Controller, and after being created it's namespace *should* be `Booking\Controller`, but my IDE is making it `Booking\src\Controller`

The `Booking` module is located inside a `module` directory in my project, and the `module` directory has been set as a Source Folder for my project:

[image: source folder setup]

Could anyone please help me find what setting I have to change to make namespaces auto generate as `Booking\Controller` instead of `Booking\src\Controller`?

Comment: Mark your `Booking\src` folder as Source root that maps to `Booking` namespace. **P.S.** AFAIK it should be PSR-4 and not PSR-0 (as you have `src` in the middle that is not present in namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Settings --> Directories;

Choose your `../module/Booking/src` folder;

Right-click --> Mark as Sources;

On the right panel, you should see your folder (blue). Click on `P` with little arrow - `Edit Root Properties`. In input field `Package prefix` put as `Booking`;

Apply/Ok all windows

[image]

On screenshot, I have different paths, but you should get the gist.

Now in `New Class` dialog window in the field `Namespace` you can choose namespace between 'with src' and 'without'.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to upvote multiple times. This has been bugging me for a _long_ time. Thanks!